# error: assigning to 'subhook_t' (aka 'subhook_struct *') from incompatible type 'void *'

Tags: c++, hook, void

I've solved 6 different errors, but no matter how far I look I keep hitting a dead end with this one error in a subhook code written in c.

```
./subhook_x86.c:470:10: error: assigning to 'subhook_t' (aka 'subhook_struct *') from incompatible type 'void *'
  hook = calloc(1, sizeof(*hook));
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

For context, hook is declared as
`subhook_t hook;`

Comment: What compiler are you using, and how are you compiling?

Comment: Also, don't `typedef` pointers.  It makes your code more difficult to read and understand.

Comment: @dbush g++ with -std=c++11, I'm trying to make a dylib with this command: g++ -dynamiclib -fPIC -o out.dylib main.cpp /Users/~~/subhook-master/subhook.c -std=c++11

Comment: You don't compile C code with a C++ compiler, not vice versa.

Comment: You should not be using `calloc()` in C++, use `new` instead, eg: `hook = new decltype(*hook);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike C, C++ doesn't allow automatic conversions from `void *` to other types.  You need to use an explicit cast.

```
hook = static_cast<subhook_t>(calloc(1, sizeof(*hook)));
```

Comment: "*C++ doesn't allow automatic conversions TO `void *`*" - yes, it does. It is only automatic conversions FROM `void*` that it doesn't allow.